# How can I generate and send an email in HTML format using data from a text file?

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks like this:
cat output_title.txt

```
C817491287  Cat: Nor      Sus: something date: 02/26/14
C858151287  Cat: Nor      Sus: really something date: 02/26/14
```

I would like to send an email in HTML format, using parameters from the file, e.g.

```
mine :firstparamter starting with C
sus: ?
date: ?
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT: CODE**

```
open (FILE, 'output_title.txt'); 
while (<FILE>) { 
   chomp; 
   ($chg, $Cat, $category, $sta, $stus, $sus, $open, $open_date) = split(" "); 
   print "Chnge is:$chg\n"; 
}
```

After doncoyote comments :

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
open (FILE, 'output_title.txt'); 
while (<FILE>) { 
  my ($Cnum,$Cat,$Sus,$Date) = m!(C\d{9})\s+Cat:\s+(\w+)\s+Sus:\s([\w\s]*?)date:\s+([\d/]+)$! ; 
  print "Cnum:$Cnum\t"; 
  print "Caty:$Cat\t"; 
  print "Stus:$Sus\t"; 
  print "opendate:$Date\n"; 
}
close (FILE); exit;
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi Vivin ,i tried to use chomp, but there is an challenge here ,open (FILE, 'output_title.txt');
 while (<FILE>) {
 chomp;
 ($chg, $Cat, $category, $sta, $stus, $sus, $open, $open_date) = split(" ");
 print "Chnge is:$chg\n";
}

the value after sus: will be having more than 1 word at times.

Comment: Do not post your code in comments, that's impossible to read. Edit the code into your question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  ,sorry about that ,this is the first time am posting here, so not sure how it looks ... just editing where ever necessary.

Comment: I am confused as to why you removed your code that I placed in the post.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, sorry i taught i have copy pasted in wrong place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are several methods to send html-mails from perl.

One is Mime::Lite.

For example:
use MIME::Lite;

Comment: @pitseeker , thanks for your answer .I would like to know how can i parse the data into variables.

Comment: Actually my comment was an accident (wanted it to be an answer) - see below.

Comment: Ok, if I get it right, you are not interested in sending a html mail, but reading in a file. You should make that more clear in the title.

Comment: @pitseeker , Not like that, first i want the file to be read and then i need that HTML part to be done.

Comment: Please learn to use the code formatting button in the editor (it's the one with '{}' on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find a regex pattern capture to define the required variables works better than split, when there are slight but quantifiable differences in the extraction text.
something like this should handle the cases provided. This could be improved but makes an ok starting point of the top of my head.

```
my (     $Cnum,           $Cat,          $Sus,            $Date   ) 
  =  m!(C\d{9})\s+Cat:\s+(\w+)\s+Sus:\s([\w\s]*?)date:\s+([\d/]+)$!
```

You should start to look into regexes in the perlretut documentation to understand what is going on. Basically the escaped letters w,d,s stand for word digit and non-printable character(spaces,tabs) respectively. The Parentheses capture the pattern and pass those as a list to the assignment variables. The square brackets define a multiple choice of characters.

Quantifiers: + is one or more, * is zero or more, and curly braces is the comma separated specified min/max. Each of the character they immediately follow. The question mark is a non-greedy * and the $ is the end of line anchor.

Comment: @doncoyote.. thanks alot.i was able to understand your explanations also. I tried to print the value first before putting it in HTML table.Am getting below error"syntax error at parsingtitle.pl line 8, near "print"
Global symbol "$Cnum" requires explicit package name at parsingtitle.pl line 8.
Execution of parsingtitle.pl aborted due to compilation errors."... pardon my knowledge in perl.

Comment: does a semi colon need to be added at end of line?

Comment: i have added semicolon  ,which came with up with one more error "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at parsingtitle.pl line 8"

Comment: which variables are you printing in the print statement? works fine for me for both those lines. Are all lines in the file same format, possiblya header line difference?

Comment: am pretty much printing all the variables, there is no header file diff.Here is my the code which am trying to execute.
code :
[
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, 'output_title.txt');
while (<FILE>) {
my ($Cnum,$Cat,$Sus,$Date) =  m!(C\d{9})\s+Cat:\s+(\w+)\s+Sus:\s([\w\s]*?)date:\s+([\d/]+)$! ;
print "Cnum:$Cnum\t";
print "Caty:$Cat\t";
print "Stus:$Sus\t";
print "opendate:$Date\n";
}
close (FILE);
exit; 
]

am not able to put this peice of code in the post.hence am putting here in comments

Comment: still works for me, add line skipping unless code matches a Cnum. `next unless m!^C\d+!;` after chomp.

Comment: ok try debugging, see if any of the lines do not match. `print "line $. does not match\n" unless m!C\d{9}\s+Cat:\s+\w+\s+Sus:\s[\w\s]*?date:\s+[\d/]+$!` in place of next if line.

Comment: Its gives doesnot match output for all the lines of the files.

Comment: ok, you need to modify the regex till it does match. maybe an extra `\s` before end of line (.txt file) or something. Try capturing just first variable from each line and so on. Where the chomp go?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are several methods to send html-mails from perl.

For example:

```
use MIME::Lite;
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From     => from_you@somedomain.com,
    To       => to_someone_else@someotherdomain.com,
    Subject  => "your mail subject",
    Type     => 'text/html',
    Data     => qq {
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr> <td>$chg</td><td>$Cat</td>.....</tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    },
);

$msg->send();
```

Comment: This really helps for the HTML part, Thanks for that.

Comment: From the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite): *"**WAIT!** MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."*

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot.. ok .. could someone please help me in getting the values from the file to be stored with desired variables.